# Reference Error: client is not defined

Tags: node.js

I am Creating REST API Call in jira using below code :-

var loginArgs = {

```
data: {
    "username": "singhharwinder@seasiainfotech.com",
    "password": "Seasia@123"
},
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

};

client.post("http://jira.atlassian.com/rest/auth/1/session",

loginArgs,function (data, response) {

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log('succesfully logged in, session:', data.session);

    var session = data.session;
    var searchArgs = {
        headers: {
            cookie: session.name + '=' + session.value,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data: {
            jql: "type=Bug AND status=Closed"
        }
    };

    client.post("http://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search", searchArgs, function (searchResult, response) {
        console.log('status code:', response.statusCode);
        console.log('search result:', searchResult);
    });
} else {
    throw "Login failed :(";
}
```

});

It is giving me "Reference Error: client is not defined".
Please help me .

Comment: Can you please post the code what you have tried?? which IDE r u using???

Comment: Show us your code plz

Comment: As said  whether you declared client in your code?? May its a module or third party library to be imported into the project...

Comment: yes it is declared in code as it is a post request to jira api.